# Error on scroll when page is loaded

Tags: bug

Here is a bug that raises using Stack Overflow. What is it about? Because of it my scrollbar could not scroll to the position where I left it before refreshing page. Can you guys please re-test it?

[image]

Comment: No repro, tried that exact page with Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: I don't know. It occurred on my machine thrice, and also checked for the same on other machine and the same problem bug appeared. so I felt like posting the question.